# Python 3.3 Side Cosine Rule Calculator Error

Tags: python, calculator, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a calculator in Python but I'm getting and error with the Cosine Rule I have put in.

This is what I have

```
x = float(input("First Side "))
y = float(input("Second Side "))
z = float(input("Angle which isn't opposite First or Second Side "))
print (" ")
print ("Side is: "+str(math.sqrt(((x**2)+(y**2))-(2*x*y*(math.cos(z)*(180/math.pi))))))
```

And this is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/---------/Python/test calc.py", line 339, in <module>
    print ("Side is: "+str(math.sqrt(((x**2)+(y**2))-(2*x*y*(math.cos(z)*(180/math.pi))))))
ValueError: math domain error
```

You work out the Cosine Rule by doing this:

```
a=√(b^2+c^2−2*b*c*cos(α))
```

In what I've done

```
x=b
y=c
z=α
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the line

```
2*x*y*(math.cos(z)*(180/math.pi))
```

you seem to be trying to convert from degrees to radians?  but (1) the factor is upside down and (2) it needs to be inside the `cos(...)`.

so you may have meant

```
2*x*y*math.cos(z*math.pi/180)
```

(check: when z is 180 degrees, the code above gives pi radians).

Answer (score 2):

It works for me; I'd imagine that you are putting in numbers that are impossible for a triangle.  Try your input in a regular calculator and see if it works.

Also, note that your angle needs to be in radians (or you need to convert it to degrees).

I tried sides of 3, 4 and 3.14/2 (approximately 90 degrees in radians) and got 4.99, which approximates the correct answer of 5.

Comment: Ooh, to be fair, I'm using Python 2.7.  Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems math.cos(z)*(180/math.pi)  is the part mistaken, making what's inside the `math.sqrt` negative for some cases.

```
print ("Side is: "+str(math.sqrt(((x**2)+(y**2))-(2*x*y*math.cos(z)))))
```

or `math.cos(z*math.pi/180)` will be what you want.

(EDIT: Corrected the upside-down fraction. Thanks: andrew cooke))

Comment: i think that's upside down.  it wants to be pi/180, not 180/pi.  consider the angle 180 degrees.  that should give a value of pi radians.